# How to calculate probability with grains per head

Tags: probability, statistics

Grain is planted and after harvesting processed. From the past is known, that there are average 25 grains per head provided. By replanting, it was more than 16 grains per head. These data $x_n$ are in the following table.

Calculate probability that the number of grains per head is between 24 and 38.

[image]

Comment: What do $ n $ and $ x_n $ represent? What have you tried so far?

Comment: $n$ is head, $x_n$ are grains. Should I calculate $P(24<x<38)$ ?

Comment: You want the probability that the **number of grains per head** is between 24 and 38. The number of grains per head is thus $ x_n / n $.

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: No. I am not sure how to use $x_n/n$ ?

Comment: I don't fully understand the background information given in the question. Where exactly does the table come from? How was that dataset collected?